# Python "or" equivalent in Swift?

Tags: python, ios, swift, operators

Due to Swift cool behaviors I was looking for an `or` equivalent in Swift.

Something like this:

```
variable = value or default
```

I coded [mine](https://gist.github.com/Francescu/f3321e1aa0ea1806e550):

```
func |<T>(a:T?, b:T) -> T {
    if let a = a {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

But I was wondering if any default implementation of this already exists in Swift?

Edit:
Thanks to answers I found the reference in the Swift book:

> **Nil Coalescing Operator**
>
> The nil coalescing operator (`a ?? b`) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if `a` is nil. The expression `a` is always of an optional type. The expression `b` must match the type that is stored inside `a`.
>
> The nil coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:
>
> ```
>     a != nil ? a! : b
> ```
>
> The code above uses the ternary conditional operator and forced unwrapping (`a!`) to access the value wrapped inside `a` when `a` is not nil, and to return `b` otherwise. The nil coalescing operator provides a more elegant way to encapsulate this conditional checking and unwrapping in a concise and readable form. ([source](https://itun.es/fr/jEUH0.l))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `??`:

```
var optional:String?
var defaultValue:String = "VALUE"

var myString:String = optional ?? defaultValue

print(myString)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the nil coalescing operator

```
let variable = optional ?? default
```